# Woocommerce how to set default_checkout_billing_country only if user is not logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I have this function and I only want to set the billing country if user is a guest, otherwise we should not change the billing country, but instead take the billing country as what the user has in his profile in WooCommerce.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country' );
 
function bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country() {
  return 'US'; 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `is_user_logged_in`:

```php
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country' );
 
function bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country($default) {

  if(is_user_logged_in()){
    return $default;
  }else{
    return 'US';
  };
   
};
```

However, sometimes, because of caching issues, `is_user_logged_in` doesn't work. In that case then you could use `global $current_user`.

```php
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country' );

function bbloomer_change_default_checkout_country($default) {

  global $current_user;

  if($current_user->ID){
    return $default; 
  }else{
    return 'US';
  };
  
};
```

Let me know if you could get it to work!